# How to Add custom manager to third-party app's model

Tags: django, django-managers

I have added `is_active` field in all my models for adding soft-deleting functionality and added a custom manager for fetching active objects

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(SoftDeleteManager, self).get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)


class Student(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active_objects = SoftDeleteManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Further, I want to add the same `active_objects` manager on `auth.User` model too but as this model is not defined in my code-base I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You should use a custom user model, even if you don't change any fields of the model. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) for how to do that. Hopefully this is not an app in production and you can still start fresh with a custom user model (change user model mid-project is complicated). For other 3rd party apps, you can always subclass a model to add the `is_active` field to the model and change the default manager or add an additional manager.

Comment: Note that you have to be a bit careful to "re-use" the `is_active` field of the `User` model to indicate soft deletion. In some cases, `is_active` is `False` until the user verifies their email address. Or users might get suspended due to suspicious activity, which is also where `is_active` might get set to `False`. So interpreting that as "deleted" might not be what you want.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks, but I am looking for a generic solution to add a custom manager to any 3rd party app. Above use case is just an example.

Comment: Well `User` is a special case so it's not a good example of a 3rd party app. For any other model, just [subclass it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) if it doesn't have the `is_active` field (because you need to add a table with that field) or if the model already has the `is_active` field, use a [**proxy model**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption: you want to soft-delete any 3rd party model that **does not** have the `is_active` field. And it should not be the `auth.User` model because that is a special case.

I'd first create an abstract model class to implement the soft-delete behaviour:

```
class SoftDeleteModel(models.Model):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    active_objects = SoftDeleteManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now suppose you have a 3rd party app with a model `Message`, then inside your app, you can subclass it:

```
from 3rdparty.models import Message as ExtMessage
from .models import SoftDeleteModel

class Message(SoftDeleteModel, ExtMessage):
    pass
```

Now your own `Message` class has the extra field and the `active_objects` manager. You will need to `makemigrations` and `migrate` because a new table will be created for `Message`.

Comment: Your solution looks good but I am looking for a solution which add custom manager on third party app without adding any new field on the existing model.

Comment: Well then create a proxy model and put the custom manager on the proxy model.

Comment: but how will the behavior will change of third-party app's code?

Comment: What do you mean “change the behavior of 3rd party app code”? In your question you said all you want is an extra manager that filters on is_active. If you instantiate an object from the proxy it will behave like the 3rd party model but will have the extra manager. You just need to make sure you always use the proxy in your own code.

Comment: let suppose, third party app is using a method of default manager and you have overridden it in your custom manager. and when third-party app calls field._default_manager.some_function then it will call the default function, not yours. This is already done in Django Deserialization code, that's why i am asking.

Comment: You explicitly wrote in your question that you **didn't** want to replace the default manager but add a new manager. But if you want, you can also replace the default manager in your proxy model. Then if the 3rd party app calls `MyModel._meta.default_manager()....` it will use the one you defined. I don't know what you mean by "Django Deserialisation" code.

Comment: It would help if your question were to be more specific. Tell us exactly which 3rd party app, which model you want to change the behavior. Tell us which method/behaviour of the 3rd party app should be overridden. Then we can better understand why model inheritance doesn't work/works.

Comment: I need to try to some code for specifying everything here. But your last comment really helped.